# Cannot `pub add geoflutterfire`

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I could not manage to add the `geoflutterfire` module.

I don't really understand what I should do as I just upgraded all modules with `flutter pub upgrade`.

Here is what I get:

```
 flutter pub add geoflutterfire
    Because cached_network_image >=3.2.0 depends on flutter_cache_manager ^3.3.0 which depends on rxdart >=0.26.0 <0.28.0, cached_network_image >=3.2.0 requires rxdart >=0.26.0 <0.28.0.
    Because geoflutterfire >=2.0.3+3 <2.0.3+7 depends on rxdart ^0.22.0 and geoflutterfire <2.0.3+3 depends on rxdart ^0.20.0, geoflutterfire <2.0.3+7 requires rxdart ^0.20.0 or ^0.22.0.
    Thus, cached_network_image >=3.2.0 is incompatible with geoflutterfire <2.0.3+7.
    And because geoflutterfire >=3.0.0-nullsafety.3 <3.0.2 depends on rxdart ^0.27.0 and geoflutterfire >=2.2.3 <3.0.0-nullsafety.1 depends on rxdart ^0.27.3, if cached_network_image >=3.2.0 and geoflutterfire <2.0.3+7 or >=2.2.3 <3.0.0-nullsafety.1 or >=3.0.0-nullsafety.3 <3.0.2-∞ then rxdart ^0.27.0.
    And because geoflutterfire >=2.2.2 <2.2.3 depends on cloud_firestore ^0.16.0 and geoflutterfire >=2.2.1 <2.2.2 depends on cloud_firestore ^0.14.0+2, if cached_network_image >=3.2.0 and geoflutterfire <2.0.3+7 or >=2.2.1 <3.0.0-nullsafety.1 or >=3.0.0-nullsafety.3 <3.0.2-∞ then rxdart ^0.27.0 or cloud_firestore ^0.14.0+2 or ^0.16.0.
(1) So, because geoflutterfire >=2.0.3+6 <2.2.1 depends on cloud_firestore ^0.13.0+1 and geoflutterfire >=3.0.0-nullsafety.1 <3.0.0-nullsafety.3 depends on cloud_firestore ^1.0.0, if cached_network_image >=3.2.0 and geoflutterfire <3.0.2 then rxdart ^0.27.0 or cloud_firestore ^0.13.0+1 or ^0.14.0+2 or ^0.16.0 or ^1.0.0.

    Because geoflutterfire >=3.0.0-nullsafety.1 <3.0.0-nullsafety.3 depends on rxdart ^0.26.0 and geoflutterfire >=3.0.0-nullsafety.3 <3.0.1 depends on cloud_firestore ^2.0.0, geoflutterfire >=3.0.0-nullsafety.1 <3.0.1 requires rxdart ^0.26.0 or cloud_firestore ^2.0.0.
    And because geoflutterfire <2.0.3+3 depends on rxdart ^0.20.0, geoflutterfire <2.0.3+3 or >=3.0.0-nullsafety.1 <3.0.1-∞ requires rxdart ^0.20.0 or ^0.26.0 or cloud_firestore ^2.0.0.
    And because geoflutterfire >=2.0.3+3 <2.0.3+7 depends on rxdart ^0.22.0 and geoflutterfire >=2.0.3+7 <2.2.1 depends on rxdart ^0.23.1, geoflutterfire <2.2.1-∞ or >=3.0.0-nullsafety.1 <3.0.1-∞ requires rxdart ^0.20.0 or ^0.22.0 or ^0.23.1 or ^0.26.0 or cloud_firestore ^2.0.0.
    And because geoflutterfire >=2.2.1 <2.2.2 depends on rxdart ^0.24.1 and geoflutterfire >=2.2.2 <2.2.3 depends on rxdart ^0.25.0, geoflutterfire <2.2.3-∞ or >=3.0.0-nullsafety.1 <3.0.1-∞ requires rxdart ^0.20.0 or ^0.22.0 or ^0.23.1 or ^0.24.1 or ^0.25.0 or ^0.26.0 or cloud_firestore ^2.0.0.
    And because geoflutterfire >=2.2.3 <3.0.0-nullsafety.1 depends on cloud_firestore ^3.1.6 and geoflutterfire >=3.0.1 <3.0.2 depends on cloud_firestore ^2.3.0, geoflutterfire <3.0.2 requires rxdart ^0.20.0 or ^0.22.0 or ^0.23.1 or ^0.24.1 or ^0.25.0 or ^0.26.0 or cloud_firestore >=2.0.0 <3.0.0 or ^3.1.6.
    And because if cached_network_image >=3.2.0 and geoflutterfire <3.0.2 then rxdart ^0.27.0 or cloud_firestore ^0.13.0+1 or ^0.14.0+2 or ^0.16.0 or ^1.0.0 (1), if cached_network_image >=3.2.0 and geoflutterfire <3.0.2 then cloud_firestore ^0.13.0+1 or ^0.14.0+2 or ^0.16.0 or ^1.0.0 or >=2.0.0 <3.0.0 or ^3.1.6.
    And because geoflutterfire >=3.0.2 depends on cloud_firestore ^3.1.6 and shokaze depends on cloud_firestore ^4.2.0, cached_network_image >=3.2.0 is incompatible with geoflutterfire.
    So, because shokaze depends on both cached_network_image ^3.2.3 and geoflutterfire any, version solving failed.
pub finished with exit code 65
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might because there are some constraints between two or more packages as you read from this message.

So, one way to resolve this is to downgrade some of these packages and then use **dependency_overrides** in pubspec.yaml to use the higher version.

There is a sample in my project, some packages have constraints with **flutter_svg**, then in the **dependencies** I use the lower version and then in **dependency_overrides** I use the high version

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_svg: ^0.22.0 ##package that needs to be overridden
```

[image: dependencies]

then

```
dependency_overrides:
  flutter_svg: ^1.1.6 ## newest version of package
```

[image: overrides]

And in your case, I have tried this and it works, you can take a look a have a try

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cloud_firestore: ^3.1.6
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.3
  
  geoflutterfire: ^3.0.3
  flutter_cache_manager: ^3.3.0
  rxdart: ^0.27.7
  flutter_lints: ^1.1.0


 dependency_overrides:
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.2.1
  flutter_svg: ^1.1.6
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.1
  cloud_firestore: ^4.3.1
```

[image: for you :3]

Comment: After you copy this to your code, kindly reminder to `flutter clean` before `pub get`

Comment: Please don't post code as images. Code should be pasted as text, and formatted using Markdown. (The toolbar in the Stack Overflow editor can help you with this.) Code within images is harder to read, less accessible, can't be copied, and doesn't show up in relevant searches. Please [edit] your post to include the code as text; this will help you get better responses, and help prevent your answer from getting deleted.

Comment: Thanks for reminder, this is my second answer, I will remember your suggestion, Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

Use geoflutterfire2 instead of geoflutterfire

flutter pub add geoflutterfire2

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by using geoflutterfire2 instead of geoflutterfire.

replace the geoflutterfire package with this "geoflutterfire2: ^2.3.15"