# Is there any way to put firebase packages in the same pubspec.yaml without generating version conflict or error in compilation phase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

What is the right SDK and the right firebase package version to run the project without errors?

```
geoflutterfire: 
firebase_core: 
cloud_firestore: 
firebase_auth: 
firebase_storage: 
firebase_messaging:
```

Errors like this

```
Because no versions of firebase_storage match >11.2.5 <12.0.0 and firebase_storage >=11.2.3 <11.2.5 depends on firebase_core ^2.14.0, firebase_storage >=11.2.3 <11.2.5-∞ or >11.2.5 <12.0.0 requires firebase_core ^2.14.0.
And because firebase_storage 11.2.5 depends on firebase_core ^2.15.0, firebase_storage ^11.2.3 requires firebase_core ^2.14.0.
So, because okleva depends on both firebase_core ^1.10.2 and firebase_storage ^11.2.4, version solving failed.
exit code 1
```

I search for solutions and after follow the steps of this link.

> https://iiro.dev/resolving-dart-package-version-conflicts/

I got this

```
   +2 ms]     FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends(_delegate);
[        ]                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[+7359 ms] [+13064 ms] ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-1.24.0/lib/src/firebase_app.dart:18:25: Error: Member not found: 'FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends'.
[   +5 ms] [   +3 ms]     FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends(_delegate);
[        ] [        ]                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[+1815 ms] ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth_platform_interface-6.10.1/lib/src/action_code_info.dart:65:15: Error: The method 'FallThroughError' isn't defined for the class
'ActionCodeInfo'.
[        ]  - 'ActionCodeInfo' is from 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/action_code_info.dart'
('../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth_platform_interface-6.10.1/lib/src/action_code_info.dart').
[        ] Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'FallThroughError'.
[        ]         throw FallThroughError();
[        ]               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[+2819 ms] ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore_platform_interface-5.7.7/lib/src/platform_interface/utils/load_bundle_task_state.dart:13:13: Error: Method not found:
'FallThroughError'.
[        ]       throw FallThroughError();
[        ]             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[+3952 ms] [+8641 ms] ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth_platform_interface-6.10.1/lib/src/action_code_info.dart:65:15: Error: The method 'FallThroughError' isn't defined for the
class 'ActionCodeInfo'.
[   +1 ms] [        ]  - 'ActionCodeInfo' is from 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/action_code_info.dart'
('../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth_platform_interface-6.10.1/lib/src/action_code_info.dart').
[   +1 ms] [        ] Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'FallThroughError'.
[        ] [        ]         throw FallThroughError();
[        ] [        ]               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[+2892 ms] [+2925 ms] ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore_platform_interface-5.7.7/lib/src/platform_interface/utils/load_bundle_task_state.dart:13:13: Error: Method not found:
'FallThroughError'.
[   +2 ms] [        ]       throw FallThroughError();
[        ] [        ]             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[+8205 ms] [+8152 ms] Persisting file store
[        ] [  +24 ms] Done persisting file store
[        ] [  +14 ms] "flutter assemble" took 35 170ms.
[        ] [   +5 ms] Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
[        ]            #0      KernelSnapshot.build (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/targets/common.dart:244:7)
[        ]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ]            #1      _BuildInstance._invokeInternal (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/build_system.dart:847:9)
[        ]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ]            #2      Future.wait.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:525:21)
[        ]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ]            #3      _BuildInstance.invokeTarget (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/build_system.dart:785:32)
[        ]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ]            #4      FlutterBuildSystem.build (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/build_system.dart:614:16)
[        ]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ]            #5      AssembleCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/assemble.dart:315:32)
[   +1 ms]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ]            #6      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1336:27)
[        ]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ]            #7      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
[        ]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ]            #8      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:212:13)
[        ]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ]            #9      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:296:9)
[        ]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ]            #10     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
[        ]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ]            #11     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:244:5)
[        ]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ]            #12     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:91:9)
[        ]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ]            #13     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
[   +4 ms]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ]            #14     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:91:3)
[        ]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ] [   +5 ms] 
[        ]            #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
[        ]            #1      AssembleCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/assemble.dart:332:7)
[        ]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ]            #2      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1336:27)
[        ]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ]            #3      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
[        ]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ]            #4      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:212:13)
[        ]            <asynchronous suspension>
[   +1 ms]            #5      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:296:9)
[        ]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ]            #6      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
[        ]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ]            #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:244:5)
[        ]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ]            #8      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:91:9)
[        ]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ]            #9      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
[        ]            <asynchronous suspension>
[        ]            #10     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:91:3)
[        ]            <asynchronous suspension>
[ +277 ms] [ +265 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 253ms
[        ] [        ] Running 0 shutdown hooks
[        ] [        ] Shutdown hooks complete
[        ] [        ] exiting with code 1
[ +195 ms] > Task :app:compileFlutterBuildDebug FAILED
[        ] :app:compileFlutterBuildDebug (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 37.052 secs.
[ +100 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[        ] * Where:
[        ] Script '/Users/benjamimgomes/Development/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1201
[        ] * What went wrong:
[        ] Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
[        ] > Process 'command '/Users/benjamimgomes/Development/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
[        ] * Try:
[        ] > Run with --debug option to get more log output.
[        ] > Run with --scan to get full insights.
[        ] * Exception is:
[        ] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
[        ]      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:147)
[        ]      at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
[        ]      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:145)
[   +2 ms]      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:133)
[        ]      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:77)
[        ]      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
[        ]      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
[        ]      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
[        ]      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
[        ]      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
[        ]      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
[   +2 ms]      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
[        ]      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
[        ]      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
[        ]      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
[        ]      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
[        ]      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
[        ]      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
[   +3 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
[        ]      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
[        ]      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
[   +2 ms]      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:74)
[        ]      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:333)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:320)
[        ]      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:313)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:299)
[        ]      at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:143)
[        ]      at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:227)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:218)
[  +73 ms]      at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:140)
[        ]      at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
[        ]      at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
[   +1 ms]      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
[        ]      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
[        ]      at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[        ] Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/benjamimgomes/Development/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
[        ]      at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:414)
[        ]      at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecAction.execute(DefaultExecAction.java:38)
[        ]      at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecActionFactory.exec(DefaultExecActionFactory.java:205)
[        ]      at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.exec(DefaultProject.java:1170)
[        ]      at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.exec(DefaultProject.java:1165)
[        ]      at org.gradle.api.Project$exec$10.call(Unknown Source)
[        ]      at BaseFlutterTask.buildBundle(/Users/benjamimgomes/Development/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle:1201)
[        ]      at BaseFlutterTask$buildBundle.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
[        ]      at FlutterTask.build(/Users/benjamimgomes/Development/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle:1326)
[   +1 ms]      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[        ]      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[        ]      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[        ]      at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
[        ]      at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:104)
[        ]      at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:58)
[        ]      at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:51)
[        ]      at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:29)
[        ]      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$3.run(TaskExecution.java:242)
[        ]      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
[        ]      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
[   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
[        ]      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
[        ]      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
[        ]      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
[        ]      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
[        ]      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
[        ]      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeAction(TaskExecution.java:227)
[        ]      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeActions(TaskExecution.java:210)
[        ]      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(TaskExecution.java:193)
[        ]      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.execute(TaskExecution.java:171)
[        ]      at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.executeInternal(ExecuteStep.java:89)
[        ]      at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.access$000(ExecuteStep.java:40)
[   +1 ms]      at .execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:140)
[        ]      at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
[        ]      at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
[        ]      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
[        ]      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
[        ]      at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[        ] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[        ] BUILD FAILED in 44s
[   +1 ms] 1 actionable task: 1 executed
[ +124 ms] Watched directory hierarchies: [/Users/benjamimgomes/Development/okleva/android]
[ +619 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... (completed in 45,4s)
[   +7 ms] Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
[   +7 ms] "flutter run" took 54 677ms.
[   +6 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:757:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1336:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:212:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:296:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:244:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:91:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:91:3)
```

Is there any way to put firebase packages in the same pubspec.yaml without generating version conflict or error in compilation phase?

Comment: Have you tried upgrading all packages? Also check this [workaround](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12627#issuecomment-400037580)

Comment: yes i did that and the cycle of errors continues.

Comment: Can you share the versions of packages you are using?

Comment: Can you do `flutter clean` to clear cache and re-install the packages with `flutter install` and try?

Comment: Yes i try and the result was the same. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried upgrading `firebase_storage` to `^12.0.0` ? And also share all your dependencies versions.

Comment: This was my dependencies version `firebase_storage: ^11.2.4
    firebase_core: ^2.12.0
    cloud_firestore: ^4.7.0
    firebase_auth: ^4.6.0` and i needed to instal geoflutterfire. I found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76769266/10296934). But i wish to know more for future situations. What do you suggest me. Was it the ideal solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many attempts. I found this solution:

1. I did futter clean.
2. Delete the pubspec.lock
3. flutter pub add package

Notice: To avoid the version error I notace that some packages need to be instaled first then other. So this was the sequence that works for me.

- geoflutterfire
- firebase_core
- cloud_firestore
- firebase_storage
- firebase_auth
- firebase_messaging

The error related to FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends(_delegate);
I think that was presented couse my project files on the lib folder was created with other version of firebase packages. Reson wy when i replace all my lib files with the default flutter main.dart file the app build without that error. So the solution for this was to overrides the firebase packages with the packages version used to create the lib files.

```
dependencies:
    geoflutterfire: ^3.0.2
    firebase_core: ^1.24.0
    cloud_firestore: ^3.5.1
    firebase_storage: ^10.3.11
    firebase_auth: ^3.11.2
    firebase_messaging: ^13.1.0

  dependency_overrides:
    firebase_storage: ^11.2.4
    firebase_core: ^2.12.0
    cloud_firestore: ^4.7.0
    firebase_auth: ^4.6.0
```

This solution was based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75330203/10296934

And thanks [Roopa M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18265570/roopa-m) for the help comments.